# I am brewing alcoholic ginger beer. How much sugar to prime it?

Tags: yeast, bottling, carbonation, priming-sugar, ginger-beer

I am looking for this ginger beer to be sweet, spicy and very fizzy. Something which should violate your tongue's human rights.

I have never produced a fizzy brew before so know nothing about priming. How much sugar can I add without blowing up the bottles?

Will appreciate any help and opinions.

Comment: What bottles? There are many kinds with different strength.

Comment: I am using standard pint sized beer bottles. Second hand as I cant afford new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It depends

Ask your bottle vendor for their strength. Then, see what's your desired vol, by comparing it with styles you know. Use [Keg Carbonation Calculator](http://www.brewersfriend.com/keg-carbonation-calculator/) to see what psi it will give you. If it is lower than design strength of your bottles, go for it. Calculate priming sugar for vol you want using [Beer Priming Calculator](http://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/) and use that much. If it's too high, aim for a lower amount.

Note: I'm not associated with site hosting these calculators, I just find them reasonably good. Other calculators give similar results.

Don't go over 3 vol unless you really, really know you can. And remember that too much gas may cause your brew to gush out of the bottle. Sometimes less is more.

If bottles are second-hand, inspect them carefully as they may be weakened by natural wear and tear. Breweries can automate this to some degree, you can't, and exploding bottle is nothing nice.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As these are assorted bottles of unknown strength I will go for 3 vol as you suggested. The calculator is great as well.